# Objective C to Swift conversion

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to translate in swift the SceneKitVehicule apple sample... and I can't figure out how to translate this line of code :

```
NSArray *pointOfViews = [self.scene.rootNode
    childNodesPassingTest:^BOOL(SCNNode *child, BOOL *stop) {
        return child.camera != nil;
    ];
```

I tried :

```
var pointOfViews = self.scene?.rootNode.childNodesPassingTest{
    (child, stop) -> Bool; return child.camera != nil }
```

but not sure of the result...

Comment: Which error are you getting if any?

Comment: I get no error, but as I don't really understand the grammar of this function.. I was wondering if my translation was correct...

Comment: I think you should specify what `child` and `stop` are in the Swift function, because it is explicit in Objective-C. In Swift: `(child: SCNNode, stop: Bool) -> Bool`.

Comment: to check the syntax use code completion on the childNodesPassingTest method, press tab until the block token is selected and press return

Comment: @vadian, I get : self.scene?.rootNode.childNodesPassingTest(predicate: (SCNNode!, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool) for the code completion... that I don't understand :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the semicolon and add `in`

```
var pointOfViews = self.scene?.rootNode.childNodesPassingTest { (child, stop) -> Bool in
  return child.camera != nil
}
```

Comment: no more from the compiler with this syntax, thks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Also, `(child: SCNNode, stop: Bool)` or without type is both fine in Swift, as the compiler already knew what should've returned:

```
    var pov = self.scene?.rootNode.childNodesPassingTest{
        (child, stop) -> Bool in
        return child.camera != nil
    }
```

Tested in a blank SceneKit project and do a `print(pov)` without error. (Xcode 7 beta 2)